# Is it true that for infinitely many values of $n$, the sum of digits of $2^n$ is greater than for $2^{n+1}$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $S(n)$ denote the digit sum of the integer $n$, using base $10$.
How to prove that there exist infinitely natural numbers such that $S(2^n)>S(2^{n+1})$?

---

Remarks (by Deven Ware):

1. This is not true in base $2$, because then the sum of digits is always $1$.
2. $S(2^n)$ is never equal to $S(2^{n+1})$ because the powers differ $\bmod 3$.

Comment: Definitely not in base $2$ :)

Comment: Why????????????

Comment: @user107678 both are 1 always.

Comment: I know that the problem intended to use base $10$ (working on it), but you should explicitly specify it. Otherwise if you were an ancient babylonian  who traveled from the past, or a robot from the future, I would be discriminating you for being of the minorities. By the way, you are getting away with this one because it is interesting enough, but the usual way of asking questions for homework here is showing your effort and thoughts, so that we can help you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to finish this one, but the following observation is likely relevant.  Consider the digits of $2^n$.  We can predict the relative change $S(2^{n+1})-S(2^n)$ from the digits in the following way: for a digit of 0, no change; digit of 1 gives +1; digit of 2 gives +2; 3 gives +3, 4 gives +4, 5 gives -4, 6 gives -3, 7 gives -2, 8 gives -1, 9 gives no change.  So you need some way of predicting a glut of digits 5-8 over digits 1-4, in an appropriate weighting, but I'm not seeing any pattern that lasts indefinitely.

Comment: Another thing I have noticed is that $2^n$ and $2^{n+1}$ cannot have the same digit sum as they are different modulo 3. So if we do not have this property, then we have the digit sums strictly increasing eventually.

Comment: @DevenWare That's not what I predict at all.  I predict 10.  The digit of 3 means the digit sum goes up by 3 at the next power.  The digit 2 means the digit sum goes up by 2 at the next power.  Combined, the digit sum goes up by 5.  5+5 = 10.

Comment: @zidabawatimmy I see I misinterpreted your comment, redacted.

Comment: @DevenWare No problem, I was trying to be brief so as not to hit the character limit before I was finished, so I expected potential confusion.

Comment: I thought "digits" implies base ten unless otherwise specified.  Maybe that's just me.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Only for beings with ten fingers.

Answer (score 23):

Expanding on Deven Ware's observation: assuming $S(2^n)$ is eventually nondecreasing, not only would it strictly increase, but we can give a non-trivial lower bound on its rate of growth.

Working mod $3$, for instance, note that if for some $m$, $S(2^m) \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, then $S(2^{m+1}) \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, so if $S(2^{m+1}) > S(2^m)$ then in fact $S(2^{m+1}) \ge S(2^m)+2$.  We can easily see this leads a lower bound of $$S(2^n) \ge \tfrac32 n + O(1),$$ which is stronger than the $n+O(1)$ lower bound one gets from just being strictly increasing.

On the other hand, since $2^n$ has $\frac{\log 2}{\log 10}n + O(1)$ digits, we have an upper bound of $$S(2^n) \le 9\frac{\log 2}{\log 10}n + O(1) < 2.71n + O(1).$$  This doesn't contradict our lower bound of $S(2^n) \ge \tfrac32 n + O(1)$, but look at what happens when we work modulo $9$ instead:

The sequence $\{2^n\}$ cycles modulo $9$ as $1,2,4,8,7,5,1,\ldots$, and $\{S(2^n)\}$ follows exactly the same cycle.  However, if we assume $S(2^n)$ is (eventually) nondecreasing, then starting from any sufficiently large $m$ such that $S(2^m) = 9k+1$, we have the chain of inequalities:

\begin{align}
S(2^{m+1}) &\ge 9k+2, \\
S(2^{m+2}) &\ge 9k+4, \\
S(2^{m+3}) &\ge 9k+8, \\
S(2^{m+4}) &\ge 9k+16, \\
S(S^{m+5}) &\ge 9k+23, \\
S(S^{m+6}) &\ge 9k+28,
\end{align}

which yields a lower bound of $S(2^n) \ge \frac{27}{6} n + O(1) = 4.5n + O(1)$.  This does contradict the upper bound from the number of digits, so indeed $S(2^n)$ must decrease infinitely often.

What homework is this from?  This is actually quite a pretty question, and I'm both pleased and impressed that it can be answered by such elementary methods.

Comment: Can you solve this for $3^n$?

Comment: @Andy It should be easy to show that $S(3^n) \ge S(3^{n+1})$ infinitely often, however I don't see a way to rule out $S(3^n) = S(3^{n+1})$ because both sides are generally congruent mod $9$.

Comment: they're actually even congruent as numbers many times :)