# On the sum of digits of $2^x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was looking into the sum of the digits of $2^x$. When I plotted y = sum of digits of $2^x$, the relationship was very linear (as one should expect) with a correlation coefficient of $0.999587$, when I calculated to $x = 10000$. However, my question concerns the slope of the line of best fit: $1.3556600856084817$. The slope seemed to fluctuate around $1.35$. **Is there any reason for this?**

[image: Graph of y = sum of digits of 2^x]

Here are the slopes for f(n), representing the slope of y = the sum of digits for n^x:
When plotted, it appears to be logarithmic.

- f(2) = 1.3556600856084817
- f(3) = 2.1458633077830696
- f(4) = 2.709191384919649
- f(5) = 3.147413019705652
- f(6) = 3.5012234023042232
- f(7) = 3.8034815099113444
- f(8) = 4.064013020137782
- (9) = 4.293926142384194
- f(11) = 4.68565515673792
- f(12) = 4.856282415979148
- f(13) = 5.0120684909979305
- f(14) = 5.156650757838338
- f(15) = 5.29277691693154
- f(35) = 6.946651885840713
- f(99) = 8.980022856020353
- f(223) = 10.56770121473439

**Does anyone have any explanation for the meaning behind these slopes?**

Here is some of my sloppy python code if you want to play around with it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sum_npx = []

#sum of digits of n^x
def sum_of_digits(integer_list):
    total_digit_sum = 0
    for number in integer_list:
        num_str = str(number)
        for char in num_str:
            if char.isdigit():
                total_digit_sum += int(char)
    return total_digit_sum

for _ in range(1, 10000):
    sum_npx.append(sum_of_digits([int(i) for i in str(2**_)]))

x = [a for a in range(1, 10000)]
plt.plot(np.unique(x), np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, sum_npx, 1))(np.unique(x)))
plt.plot(x, sum_npx)
plt.show()

df = {
    "Array 1": x,
    "Array 2": sum_npx
}

coefficients = np.polyfit(x, sum_npx, 1)

# Extract the slope (coefficient for x, which is the first element)
slope = coefficients[0]

# Print the slope
print("Slope of the line of best fit:", slope)

data = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(data.corr())
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I presume you are referring to the digits of 2^x **in base 10**.

Comment: Yes, in base 10.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but I immediately thought of Benford's Law. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law

Comment: @LamarLatrell Note that [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law#Generalization_to_digits_beyond_the_first) implies that the distribution of the $n$-th digit, as $n$ increases, rapidly approaches a *uniform* distribution.

Comment: [An older related thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1102553/11619).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

$2^x$ has about
$$
\log_{10}(2^x) = x\log_{10}(2) \approx 0.30103x
$$
digits in base $10$.
The average digit is about $4.5$, so the sum of the digits is about
$$
4.5 \log_{10}(2)x \approx 1.35 x.
$$

This argument generalizes to show that the sum of the base $b$ digits of $n^x$ is about
$$
\frac{b-1}{2}\log_{b}(n) x
$$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150048/discussion-on-answer-by-ethan-bolker-on-the-sum-of-digits-of-2x); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 7):

It may be worth noting how well the **wedge-like shape** of this plot is explained by the assumption that the digits of $2^x$ are approximately uniformly distributed (and independent). The mean and variance of the sum of these digits in this case are easily found to be as follows:
$$\mu(x)=4.5\times (\text{number of digits in $2^x$})$$  $$\sigma^2(x)=8.25\times(\text{number of digits in $2^x$})$$
Computations show (in the plot on the left) that the two lines $\mu(x)\pm 3\,\sigma(x)$ almost perfectly outline the plot, with $\mu(x)$ being the center line:

[image: plot of sum-of-digits of 2^x and histogram of standardized values]

The plot on the right shows the approximate normality of the sums-of-digits by using their standardized values $$Z(x)={\text{sum-of-digits$(2^x)$}-\mu(x)\over\sigma(x)},$$
the blue curve being the standard normal density function.

---

SageMath code for the plot on the left:

```
def sum_of_digits(x, n, b):
    return sum((n^x).digits(base=b))
def mu(x, n, b):
    return ((b - 1) / 2) * (1 + floor(log(n^x, b)))
def sd(x, n, b):
    return sqrt( ((b^2 - 1) / 12) * (1 + floor(log(n^x, b))))
b = 10
n = 2
xmax = 10^4
L = [(x, sum_of_digits(x,n,b)) for x in range(xmax)]
Lmu = [(x, mu(x,n,b)) for x in range(xmax)]
Llo = [(x, mu(x,n,b) - 3.0*sd(x,n,b)) for x in range(xmax)]
Lhi = [(x, mu(x,n,b) + 3.0*sd(x,n,b)) for x in range(xmax)]
gr = line(L, color='orange')
gr += line(Lmu, linestyle=':', color='black')
gr += line(Llo, linestyle=':', color='blue')
gr += line(Lhi, linestyle=':', color='blue')
gr.show(axes_labels=[r'Integer $x$', 'Sum of digits'],
    axes_labels_size=1, frame=True, axes=False, 
    title=r'Sum of base-${%s}$ digits in ${%s}^x$ versus $x$'%(str(b),str(n)), figsize=4)
```

Comment: +1 definitely worth noting.

Comment: I wonder whether what seems to be a very slight skew in the histogram is a real second order effect. What happens if you sample between the integers and use the sum of the digits of the integral part of the power?

Comment: That's an  interesting idea -- I'll check it out. For now, I notice that the slight "shoulder" on the right in the histogram seems to be an effect that vanishes as sample size increases -- at $10^5$ it's still just barely visible.

Comment: Using $\lfloor n^x\rfloor$ with $x$ varying in fractional step-sizes, I find that (as expected) the skewness & kurtosis measures of the $Z$-sample both decrease towards $0$ with increasing sample size. Curiously, sampling with (x=1..10^4,step=0.1) produces measurably less skew and kurtosis than does (x=1..10^5,step=1), although both have sample size 10^5; and both of those are of course significantly less than with (x=1..10^4,step=1). The (mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis) for these three cases are, respectively, (-.03, 1.004,-.002,-.007),(-.008,1.000,-.009,-.01), and (.01,1.003,-.01,-.1).