# On the Digit Sum of Primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was playing around with the sum of the digits of various sequences, including [the sum of the digits of $2^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4811109/on-the-sum-of-digits-of-2x), when I plotted the sum of the digits of primes in python (y= sum of digits of the xth prime). The resulting scatter plot was, in my opinion, very interesting. It seemed to oscillate in an upwards slope, in a jagged manner. Does anyone have any explanation concerning the nature of the graph?

[image: y = sum of the digits of the xth prime]

I ran my program until x = 10000. The graph correlation coefficient of $0.498144$. If anyone has any input on the matter, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my sloppy python code if anyone wants to play around with it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

RANGE = 100000

prime_sum_digits = []
def sum_of_digits(num):
    total_digit_sum = 0
    num_str = str(num)
    for char in num_str:
        if char.isdigit():
            total_digit_sum += int(char)
    return total_digit_sum

def prime(RANGE):
    prime_list = []
    for i in range(1, RANGE):
        if i == 0 or i == 1:
            continue
        else:
            for j in range(2, int(i/2)+1):
                if i % j == 0:
                    break
            else:
                prime_list.append(i)
    return prime_list

#print((prime(RANGE)))

for prime in prime(RANGE):
    prime_sum_digits.append(sum_of_digits(prime))

#print(prime_sum_digits)

x_axis = [a for a in range(1, len(prime_sum_digits) + 1)]
y_axis = prime_sum_digits
plt.plot(np.unique(x_axis), np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x_axis, y_axis, 1))(np.unique(x_axis)))
plt.scatter(x_axis, y_axis, s=10, c='blue')
plt.show()

df = {
    "x-th prime": x_axis,
    "sum of digits": y_axis
}

coefficients = np.polyfit(x_axis, y_axis, 1)

# Extract the slope (coefficient for x, which is the first element)
slope = coefficients[0]

# Print the slope
print("Slope of the line of best fit:", slope)

data = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(data.corr())
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plot the graph with all natural numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Restricting to primes is actually a red herring here. I've plotted the primes (in black), all natural numbers (in blue), and all natural numbers except those divisible by $3$ (in red) in the following.

[image: prime digit sums]

[image: all natural number digit sums]

[image: non3 digit sums]

As you can see, the question is really *why do generic natural numbers have sums of digits with these patterns?* And there are some things that can be explained pretty well.

The wedges restart every $10^5$, as the numbers $n \cdot 10^5$ have "small" digit sums $n$. This is an artifact of our base system and the region I chose to plot. (I note that I didn't include the point $10^6$ in my plots --- so we don't see the *next* time a number has digit sum $1$).

Comment: I disagree with saying "the question is really *why do generic natural numbers have sums of digits with these patterns?*"  It isn't that primes are a "red herring", but rather I think that's still not the **real question**, which is "Why do the prime numbers (unlike powers of two) behave like the natural numbers in this regard?"

Comment: The answer is because the primes are quite dense within the natural numbers, while powers of 2 are not.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the situation for powers of two, the **digits** of the $n$th prime $(p_n)$ have some definite patterns as a function of $n$ that significantly affect the sum-of-digits; in particular, when $p_n$ is just above a large power of ten there will be many $0$s, tending to gradually decrease in number as $p_n$ grows toward the next-larger power of ten. Within that range, there will also be fine-structure due to the very same phenomenon. The effect on the **sum-of-digits** is therefore to have an increasing trend composed of many oscillations. There's a resulting "fractal-like" structure that becomes more evident as $n$ increases -- here's a plot for a million primes:

[image]

---

SageMath:

```
def sum_of_digits(n,b): return sum(nth_prime(n).digits(base=b))
b = 10; nmax = 10^6
L = [(n, sum_of_digits(n,b)) for n in range(1,nmax+1)]
line(L, color='orange').show(axes_labels=[r'$n$', 'Sum of digits'], 
        axes_labels_size=1, frame=True, axes=False, figsize=4)
```

Comment: But this has nothing to do with the numbers being prime.

Comment: @GregMartin  I guess the point is that the explanation I give for the primes also happens to apply to the naturals (but not to the powers of two).

Answer (score -2):

You have numbers from 1 to 10,000. The thousands digit goes up by one every 1,000. For each thousand numbers, the 100s go from 0 to 9 so we go up by 9 within each group of 1000.

Comment: The OP's graph has numbers up to 100,000. There are 9592 prime numbers in this range.

Comment: @DanielMathias The OP's graph used 10,000, but their program code has 100,000.

Comment: @r.e.s. The x-axis of the graph is the number of primes, not the prime numbers. The graph was generated by the program code and has data for the first 9592 primes. That is all primes less than 100,000.

Comment: @DanielMathias Ah, I misread -- sorry to mix apples & oranges.