# Is the sum of digits of $\left(16^k - 1\right)$ less than $6k$ for $k > 223$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I had been researching the OEIS sequence [A165722](http://oeis.org/A165722), which is the sequence of positive integers $k$ such that the sum of digits of $\left(16^k - 1\right)$ is equal to $6k$. I used computational power to determine that the sum of digits is less than $6k$ for $223 < k < 10^6$. I made a conjecture that $6k$ would continue to grow at a faster rate than the digit sum, and thus the sequence is finite. I and several others, however, were unsure how one would go about proving this. I thought that perhaps there would be some way to show a regularity in the digits of $16^k - 1$, but I would not know how to go about finding or proving this regularity.

Comment: I don't think that there is hope to find such a regularity. Besides the few last digits, the digits will probably behave like a random sequence. We can expect that the average digit does not exceed $4.5$ significant, but we would need an average digit of about $4.98$ to have $6k$ digits or more. So, the digitsum should always be less than $6k$ for $k>223$. I would be very surprised if someone can prove this.

Comment: Legendre's formula might be a good starting: if $\nu_q(n)$ denotes the sum of digits in the $q$-ary expansion of $n$, then $$ \nu_q(n) = n - (q-1)\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{q^j} \right\rfloor = (q-1)\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{n\text{ mod }q^j}{q^j}. $$ But again, this leads us to an intricate world of multiplicative groups and I have no idea. I would also be very surprised if someone can prove this.

Comment: I don't know if this applies, but perhaps you could use Benfords law to do a statistical/probabilistic analysis of the digits of $16^k-1$ and then show that the probability of getting a number whose digit sum is equally to 6k is greater than 0. Once again though, I'm not sure if Benford's law applies. Perhaps you could find a distribution for the digits in base 16.

Comment: Here's a proof of a very weak lower bound, showing that the sum of the base-$10$ digits of $2^n$ is $\Omega(\log n)$: http://oeis.org/A001370/a001370_1.pdf

Comment: @mjqxxxx Would that mean that the digit sum of $2^n$ is greater than or equal to $\log n$?

Comment: Greater than $A \log n$ for some constant $A > 0$, for sufficiently large $n$.  This is clearly weaker than what you need; the point is that any stronger bound than this seems to be open.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Ah, okay, well thank you for the insight.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Also, I believe that I am more looking for an upper bound for the digit sum if possible. If I were to find, for example that the sum has an upper bound of $O(x^n)$ for any $n<1$, then I would at least know there is some point at which the sum will be less than $6k$.

Comment: [This somewhat related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879033/11619) may be of interest. I hastily misread it, and thought it came close to proving yours. It doesn't, but it may be of interest anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Some preliminary estimates**. From [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Number-Theory-Structures-Examples-Problems/dp/081763245X/ref=sr_1_28?ie=UTF8&qid=1524996868&sr=8-28&keywords=number%20theory), page 79 (accessible in preview mode)
$$S(16^n-1)=16^n-1 - 9\sum\limits_{k\geq1} \left \lfloor \frac{16^n-1}{10^k} \right \rfloor \tag{1}$$

---

[Further](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part)
$$S(16^n-1)=
16^n-1 - 9\sum\limits_{k\geq1} \left(\frac{16^n-1}{10^k}-\left\{\frac{16^n-1}{10^k}\right\}\right)=\\
16^n-1 - 9\sum\limits_{k\geq1} \frac{16^n-1}{10^k}+9\sum\limits_{k\geq1}\left\{\frac{16^n-1}{10^k}\right\}=\\
(16^n-1)\left(1 - 9\sum\limits_{k\geq1} \frac{1}{10^k}\right)+9\sum\limits_{k\geq1}\left\{\frac{16^n-1}{10^k}\right\}=\\
(16^n-1)\left(1 - 9\left(\frac{10}{9}-1\right)\right)+9\sum\limits_{k\geq1}\left\{\frac{16^n-1}{10^k}\right\}=
9\sum\limits_{k\geq1}\left\{\frac{16^n-1}{10^k}\right\}$$
Or
$$S(16^n-1)=9\sum\limits_{k\geq1}\left\{\frac{16^n-1}{10^k}\right\}\tag{2}$$

---

The last digit of $16^n-1$ is always $5$ and 
$$\left\{\frac{16^n-1}{10^k}\right\}=0.\overline{a_1a_2...a_{k-1}5} \leq 0.99..95<1$$
$9$ repeated $k-1$ times. But only for the first $n\log_{10}16$ terms. For all $k>n\log_{10}16$
$$\left\{\frac{16^n-1}{10^k}\right\}\leq 0.00..099..95$$
where $00..099..9$ is of length $k-1$. Basically, starting with $k\geq \left \lfloor n\log_{10}16 \right \rfloor+1$ this tail forms an infinite geometric progression with ratio $\frac{1}{10}$ which sums to a constant. So we can conclude
$$S(16^n-1) < 9n\log_{10}16 + C$$
We also have that [$9\log_{10}16<11$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9*log_10(16)), thus
$$S(16^n-1) < 11n+ C \tag{3}$$
Probably, with more accurate calculations, a better estimate may be obtained ... work in progress.

Comment: This is very nice. I do know that for some values, $S(16^n - 1) \geq 6n$, but the last apparent occurrence of this is when $n=223$. I am concerned about values above this. This is a great start though.

Comment: This bound is fairly trivial... the number $16^k-1$ has no more than $1 + \log_{10}(16^k-1) < 1 + k \log_{10}16$ digits, each of which is no greater than $9$, so the digit sum is no greater than $9 + 9k\log_{10}16 < 10.85k + 9.$

Comment: @mjqxxxx 1st of all to reveal a formula and secondly to engage more people in finding a better estimate. The weak part in the subsequent calculations is of course the gross estimate of $0.\overline{a_1a_2...a_{k-1}5} \leq 0.99..95<1$, maybe somebody could find a finer pattern? It matches your calculations, but it has, imo, more potential ...

Comment: Knowing the fractional part of $16^n-1$ over $10^k$ is the same as knowing the digits of $16^n-1$ since dividing by $10^k$ just shifts it, preserving the significant digits. This work can also be skipped using the trivial bound: $16^n-1$ has $\log_{10}(16^n-1)\approx n\log_{10}(16)$ digits in decimal, and each digit can be at most $9$ giving the bound $9n\log_{10}(16)$ as you have.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S\left(n\right)$ be the sum of the digits of $n$. Since $16^k-1$ is divisible by 5 but not 2, the last digit is five, and hence $$S\left(16^k-1\right)=S\left(16^k\right)-1$$
Essentially we want to say that $16^k=2^{4k}$ typically has digits less than 5 rather than digits more than five, or at least it doesn't mostly have digits more than five. One thought that pops out is that the map $k\mapsto2k\textrm{ mod }10$ is periodic for even $k$ with period 4 (we have the cycle $2\mapsto4\mapsto8\mapsto6\mapsto2$), and for odd $k$ of course the next term is even. Except for when there is carrying, this map is the map taking digits of $2^k$ to $2^{k+1}$. Could this periodicity which matches $2^{4k}$ explain it?