# Sum of digits of $a^b$ equals $ab$

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion, conjectures

The following conjecture is one I have made today with the aid of computer software.

> **Conjecture:**
>
> Let $s(\cdot)$ denote the sum of the digits of $\cdot$ in base $10$.  Then the only integer values $a,b>1$ that satisfy $$s(a^b)=ab$$ are $(2,2),(3,3),(3,6),(3,9)$ and $(3,27)$.

**Remarks:**

- The number of digits of an integer $n$ is $1+\lfloor\log_{10}n\rfloor$ where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ denotes the floor function. This means that $s(a^b)<9+9\lfloor b\log_{10} a\rfloor$ as each digit takes a value of at most $9$. From [this plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pxcio1lttl) it is evident that the equality will never hold for $a\ge 9$, after checking the first $21$ values of $b$. Therefore it suffices to consider $2\le a\le 8$.
- I have excluded the case $b=1$ as it is trivial - it forces $a$ to be a single-digit integer.
- In PARI/GP the code is given by `mfun(b)={for(i=2,8,for(j=2,b,if(sumdigits(i^j,10)==i*j,print(i," ",j))));}` and tests up to $b\le 10^6$ verify the above conjecture.

**Aside:**

- The equation $s(ab)=a+b$ is much simpler to solve. From [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rovagd1hao), the upper bound $a\le 23$ is apparent and for these values of $a$, we can form the upper bound $b\le 22$ as there will be no solutions when the red line lies above the blue lines. This $23\times22$ grid can be computed through software and it is found that the only solutions are $$(a,b)=(2,2),(3,6),(6,3).$$ The similarity in the first two solutions with the conjectured solutions may only be coincidental.

Advances on this will be appreciated.

Comment: So, you are only considering base-10? If such a conjecture is true, you would expect it to be true for any base.

Comment: No @alex811 function s() is attached to base $10$.

Comment: Though, in light of @alex811's comment, one wonders what the set of pairs would be in other bases.  For example, $(a,a)$ will work in any base where $(a,a)$ is represented by a single digit.  I also wonder if the fact that $3^2 = 9 = 10-1$ is of any relevance.

Comment: If $3\mid a$ then $9\mid s(a^b)$ so you need either $9\mid a$ or $3\mid b$. Don't know if that helps. I prepared a largely useless plot [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1105840/11619) related to the case $a=2$. I found [this somewhat related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879033/11619) the most delightful contribution around this theme.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: $3^3$ is a single digit in any base $n>27$, but $s_n(27)=27$ is not equal to $9$.

Comment: Showing that $s_2(2^b) < 2b$ for $b$ large is probably very difficult. I don't know how to show, for instance, that a power of $2$ can't have all 7's,8's, or 9's in its decimal expansion.

Comment: what happens if you use $s(a^b) < 9 + 9 b \log(a)$ without floor? This makes inequality only stronger. On the other hand, you can now compare $9 b \log(a)$ and $ab$, that reduces to comparison between $9 \log(a)$ and $a$ that should be $9 \log(a) < a$ after some threshold (say $a> 10$).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I posted a new question regarding my effort to solve your conjecture, to get advice about some asymptotic relation for s(a^b). Any help would be appreciated. I am not a professional mathematician, but I think it's worth reading! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370010/can-this-heuristic-argument-be-useful-to-prove-sum-of-digits-of-ab-equals-a

Comment: Asymptotics of $a=2$ is an open problem. See [A001370](https://oeis.org/A001370) comment: "It is believed that $s(2^b) \sim b\cdot \left(4.5\log_{10}(2)\right)$, but this is an open problem."

Answer (score 14):

I like to crack numbers but this time I'll pass. It's highly unlikely that there is any other solution. I have created a few plots of function:

$$f(a)=s(a^b)-ab$$

...for $a=2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ and $b\in [1,4000]$. All these plots look the same. The function slides towards negative infinity in a pretty linear fashion, with very little variation from the straight line. If you accept bets, I can bet a house that there are no other solutions except small ones that you already listed.

Mathematica code:

```
For[a=2,a<=8,a++,DiscretePlot[Total[IntegerDigits[a^b,10]]-a*b,{b,2,4000},Filling->f,Joined->False] // Print]
```

$a=2$

[image]

$a=3$

[image]

$a=4$

[image]

$a=5$

[image]

$a=6$

[image]

$a=7$

[image]

$a=8$

[image]

Comment: It looks like there may be hope in providing a linear upper bound for $f$, which would prove the result. A weak one would suffice.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a heuristic argument (not a proof sadly, but too long for a comment).

The sequences $2^n,3^n,\dots,9^n$ are known to follow Benford's law, *i.e.*, their first digit has a probability $\log_{10}\left(1+\frac{1}{d}\right)$ of being $d$; their second digit has a probability $\log_{10}\left(1+\frac{1}{10+d}\right)+\log_{10}\left(1+\frac{1}{20+d}\right)+\dots+\log_{10}\left(1+\frac{1}{90+d}\right)$ of being $d$, etc.

Here, "probability" is to be understood as asymptotic density. For instance, for the first digit of the sequence $2^n$, we have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\{k\in\{1,\dots,n\}:2^k\text{ has $d$ as first digit}\}|}{n} = \log_{10}\left(1+\frac{1}{d}\right)$$
and more generally, for all $a \in \{2,\dots,9\}$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\{k\in\{1,\dots,n\}:a^k\text{ has $d$ as $j$-th digit}\}|}{n} = \sum_{i=10^{j-2}}^{10^{j-1}-1}\log_{10}\left(1+\frac{1}{10i+d}\right)$$
and as the last quantity approaches $\frac 1 {10}$ as $j \to \infty$, the $j$-th digit of $a^n$ are almost equidistributed.

If we heuristically take these probabilities at face value, the sum of the digits of $a^n$ should match the sum of their expected values, and, apart from the first figures, this expected value is close to $4.5$. Thus, we should expect to have:
$$s(a^n) \approx 4.5(1+\lfloor n\log_{10}a\rfloor) \approx 4.5 n\log_{10}a$$
and thus:
$$s(a^n) - an \approx (\underbrace{4.5\log_{10} a - a}_{<0 \textrm{ for all } a})n \to_{n \to\infty} -\infty$$
This aligns with the graphs provided by @Oldboy. For instance, for $a=6$, we should expect a slope of $4.5\log_{10}6 - 6 \approx -2.50$, which matches the observed slope of $-10000/4000$.

Answer (score 3):

Also not an answer, but it greatly reduces the set of possible solutions... We know for a fact that the difference between $n$ and $s\left(n\right)$ is always a multiple of $9$:
$$ \left(n-s\left(n\right)\right)\mod9=0 $$
So if $s\left(a^{b}\right)=ab$, then:
$$\left(a^{b}-ab\right)\mod9=0$$
Therefore, for $2\leq a \leq 8$, $b$ must be of the following forms:
$$
b\begin{cases}
3n & \iff a=3~or~6\\
9n+1 & \iff a=4~or~7\\
18n+1~or~18n+2 & \iff a=2\\
18n+1~or~18n+8 & \iff a=8\\
18n+1~or~18n+14 & \iff a=5\\
\end{cases}
$$