# Sum of decimal digits of $2^n$ tends to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For every positive integer $n$, let $s(n)$ be the sum of the decimal digits of $n$. Is it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}s(2^n)=\infty$?

Comment: What have you tried? It's very likely since the number of digits grows without bound and almost all of them would have to be $0$ often for their sums to have a fixed bound infinitely often

Comment: The statement was proved by Schinzel , see Sierpinski, "250 problems in elementary number theory".

Comment: Yes. Have a look [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.02839.pdf). The statement seems obvious but the proof is not trivial.

Comment: @EthanBolker I did try and have the same intuition, but as Andreas and markvs pointed out the proof is not trivial at all. Thanks for your help!

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/560624/11619) for a curious related observation (=the sequence of sums never becomes monotonic).

Comment: You may want to add a link to that other question. For it adds some context to the question. Something it is currently lacking, and having some [will prevent negative attention to your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) (such as downvotes and votes to close).

Comment: It's an interesting problem, but you should at least do some modestly extended examples to get evidence for the proposition (or against it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific question is nontrivial and has already been answered in the comments but here is a much more general statement, as shown in Theorem 3 on the last page of the paper ["PV-numbers and sets of multiplicity"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02018464.pdf):

**Theorem:**
The number of integers, the sum of whose digits in each of the bases $\theta$ and $\phi$ lies below a fixed bound, is finite if and only if $\log{\theta}/\log{\phi}$ is irrational.

Nota bene: The irrationality of $\log{\theta}/\log{\phi}$ is equivalent to the [multiplicative independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_independence) of $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Given that $2^n$ always has a finite sum of digits in base $2$, the theorem shows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}s(2^n)=\infty$ in any base $b$ where $b$ is multiplicatively independent from $2$.