# Reference request: A. Schinzel on digital sums of powers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, decimal-expansion, diophantine-approximation

I am searching for the earliest published proof of the following result:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} s(2^k) = \infty$$
where $s(n)$ denotes the sum of the decimal digits of $n$.

This problem has been discussed [previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4354210/sum-of-decimal-digits-of-2n-tends-to-infty-as-n-to-infty) on Math.SE. It is proved in the book [250 Problems in Elementary Number Theory](https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/250%20Problems%20in%20Elementary%20Number%20Theory%20-%20Sierpinski%20(1970).pdf) (1970) by Wacław Sierpiński, on page 103. The author attributes the proof to Andrzej Schinzel (1937-2021), but he does not provide a reference.

It is known that $\lim_{k\to\infty} s(b^k) = \infty$ for every positive integer $b$, excluding powers of 10. More generally, if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that $\log(a)/\log(b)$ is irrational, and if $M$ is a positive integer, then there are only finitely many positive integers whose digital sums in base $a$ and $b$ are both less than $M$. This was proved by [H. G. Senge and E. G. Straus](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02018464) in 1973.